# Thread.CurrentPrincipal returning empty string

Tags: .net, multithreading

I'm trying to get `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` and it seems to be returning an empty string.

I've tried running as administrator and as a different user and it's still doing it. If I go to the `Claims` on the object, the issuer was `LOCAL AUTHORITY`. Shouldn't this then return the user I'm logged in as?

```
public string GetCurrentUser()
        {
            var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;

            //Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity
            return principal;
        }
```

Comment: Use Environment.UserName instead.

Answer (score 1):

[CurrentPrincipal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx) property uses internal `GetThreadPrincipal` method of [AppDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain(v=vs.110).aspx) type to build `IPrincipal` object by default.

```
internal IPrincipal GetThreadPrincipal()
{
  IPrincipal principal;
  if (this._DefaultPrincipal == null)
  {
    switch (this._PrincipalPolicy)
    {
      case PrincipalPolicy.UnauthenticatedPrincipal:
        principal = (IPrincipal) new GenericPrincipal((IIdentity) new GenericIdentity("", ""), new string[1]
        {
          ""
        });
        break;
      case PrincipalPolicy.NoPrincipal:
        principal = (IPrincipal) null;
        break;
      case PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal:
        principal = (IPrincipal) new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
        break;
      default:
        principal = (IPrincipal) null;
        break;
    }
  }
  else
    principal = this._DefaultPrincipal;
  return principal;
}
```

GetThreadPrincipal method uses [PrincipalPolicy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.principalpolicy(v=vs.110).aspx) which is `UnauthenticatedPrincipal` by default.

You can change default behavior. For example you can use [SetPrincipalPolicy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setprincipalpolicy(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `AppDomain` with `PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal` to get a Windows user

```
    var appDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    appDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
    var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    var user = principal.Identity.Name;
```